Is it correct to say "the crow had the idea of putting stones into the pot to make the water rise up"?
We have the structure "to have an idea of doing something"?
Does the "doing something" here refer to a purpose/goal?
Can we put detail and the way to achieve the goal into the "doing something"?
A crow couldn't reach the water in a pot with his beak. So,
Is it correct to say "the crow had the idea of making the water in the pot rise up"?
or "the crow had the idea of putting stones into the pot to make the water rise up"?
The goal: to make the water in the pot rise up
The way/method to achieve that goal: to put some stones into the pot.

Water rises, it doesn't rise up unless there is a line or point you are measuring. People rise up when involved in rebellions or revolutions. The water at high tide rose or rose up over the road and covered it.

In "an idea of doing something", "of doing something" defines what the idea is. Similarly "I have no idea of what word to use". In "the crow had the idea of putting stones into the pot to make the water rise up", the crow's idea is to put stones in the pot to make the water rise up; presumably its goal is to get a drink.

Raise the level of the water / make the water level rise

had the idea to {verb} and had the idea of {verbing} are both well-attested, though not in the context of crows.
You can search Google with the phrases "had the idea to" and "had the idea of" and look for examples in Google Books, discarding those that are not germane.
You could say

The crow had the idea {to drop | of dropping} stones into the pot to make the water rise.

Compare:

During a lull in the wartime filming of Tiefland, Riefenstahl had the idea to make a film about Vincent Van Gogh. (The Films of Leni Reifenstahl by David B. Hinton. Plymouth UK, 2000.)


Baader had the idea of carrying railway wagons on large-size road vehicles.  (The Railway Gazette,1959. Vol. 110, p. 15)
Levi-Straus went into partnership with  with a tailor from Reno, Jacob W. Davis, who had ... the idea of making trousers for wood-cutters that had back-pockets fixed on by rivets. (The Colours of Our Memories by Michel Pastoureau, translated by Janet Lloyd. Cambridge, 2020.


@Tom (BUT, I would say, reading your question, the first answer I was going to make was that "had the idea to [verb]" was more idiomatic than "had the idea of [verbing]." Maybe that's especially true with this Aesop's-crow example, in which the stones in the pot are such a discreet action. The -ing might be more at home with general or ongoing activities, like "I had the idea of swimming.")

I think you could pretty much use the two interchangeably. To my ear, had the idea of {verbing} sounds talky and colloquial whereas had the idea to {verb} sounds more polished.

It's funny, he got the structure right: have the idea of doing something, you try to make it something else, and completely miss commenting on the howler: the make the water rise up. Personally, I don't think a to infinitive is necessarily more polished. He tends to concentrate on spoken forms, anyway. Finally, a crow  putting stones in a pot requires little polish.

@Lambie I am happy to leave commenting on howlers to you.
